# Data Flow ERROR java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-dataflow, data-pipeline

I have to create the pipeline to transfer the data from BigQuery and save it as json file. But I got this error. The result from sql query is 30 million records. How to improve this code?

Error:

> [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> [error]

```js
    object tmp {
      private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
      var date = "2023-05-22"

      def main(cmdlineArgs: Array[String]){
        val (sc, args) = ContextAndArgs(cmdlineArgs)
        val file_path = "src/main/scala/thunder/tmp.sql"
        val sql_content = Source.fromFile(file_path).mkString
        val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(sql_content).build()
        val client = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
        val queryResult = client.query(queryConfig)
        var result = queryResult.iterateAll().iterator().asScala.map(_.asScala.map(_.getValue).toArray).toSeq
        val json_result = result.map { row =>
          val pin_username = row(0).toString
          val feature_name = row(1).toString
          implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
          write(Map(("pin_username"->pin_username),("feature_name" -> feature_name)))

        }
        sc.parallelize(json_result)
          .saveAsTextFile("output", ".json")

        sc.close().waitUntilFinish()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to either increase the JVM memory or write to the file record per record, i.e. not reading the entire result into memory.

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` is mainly caused by **very high memory load on your workers** since you are dealing with 30 million records of SQL query. One way to resolve this issue is to **increase the workers' memory**. It is best to set the size of your worker to `n1-highmem-4 or above`. This parameter can be used in choosing your [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1-high-memory): `--workerMachineType`.

Another workaround is you can also check through **heap dump** to determine the **out-of-memory (OOM)** errors when JVM runs out of memory. Re-run the jobs with flags `--dumpHeapOnOOM` to save the heap dump locally and `--saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath=gs://<path_to_a_gcs_bucket>` to save it on a specific bucket which you have **write permissions** on. But using heat dump is only recommended when debugging since it has another cost on top of your current service.